Problema al rellenar select HTML
Estoy intentando rellenar un SELECT con datos de una tabla MYSQL y no consigo que se rellene el SELECT sin repetir toda la página. A ver si alguien me echa una mano. El objetivo es rellenar el SELECT embebiendo el menor código posible PHP.
Pongo el código del HTML y el PHP
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form action="sistema.php" method="post">
        <label>Nombre: </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre">
        <br><br>                
        <label>Puesto de trabajo: </label>
        <select name="puestos" id="puestos">        
            <?php require_once("includes/RellenarSelect.php")?>
            <strong>AaAa</strong>
            <strong> <option value="{Id_Puesto}">{nombre}</option></strong>            
            <strong>AaAa</strong>
        </select>
        <br><br>        
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>    
</body>
</html>

Aquí el código PHP. Con la consulta a la base de datos y
<?php    
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","","", "");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM puestos";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query("$consulta");

    //Defino la expresión regular
    $regex = "/AaAa/";    
    //Busco la expresión regular en el archivo _index.php
    preg_match($regex, file_get_contents('index.php'),$array_coincidencias);

    $comodines =array('{Id_Puesto}','{nombre}');        
    $render_options = '';
    $codigo = file_get_contents('index.php');   

    foreach($resultado as $array_asociativo){        
        $sustituciones = array_values($array_asociativo);                
        $render_options .= str_replace($comodines, $sustituciones, $codigo); 
    }   
        
        print str_replace($codigo, $render_options, file_get_contents('index.php'));
    
    $mysqli->close();
?>       
  


Asumiendo que en $render_options tendrías todos los option que necesitas, tendrías que colocarlos dentro de tu select en la parte del HTML. Es cuestión de reorganizar el código para que quede ahí. Dicho eso, no entiendo cuál es el sentido de tus preg_match, file_get_contents, array_values y str_replace en este código. ¿Por qué los usas, algunos de ellos varias veces?

parece codigo que da ChatGPT cuando le hacen preguntas mal hechas XD

Veo varios errores, este es tu codigo:
    <select name="puestos" id="puestos">        
        <?php require_once("includes/RellenarSelect.php")?>
        <strong>AaAa</strong>
        <strong> <option value="{Id_Puesto}">{nombre}</option></strong>            
        <strong>AaAa</strong>
    </select>


El require_once("includes/RellenarSelect.php") debe devolver un string con los options armados y los debe estar imprimiendo:

$render_options .= str_replace($comodines, $sustituciones, $codigo); // no se que hace esto pero esta mal.

deberia de ser:
$render_options = '';
...
...
$render_options .= '<option value="'.$array_asociativo["valor"].'">'.$array_asociativo["valorOrTexto"].'</option>'
...
...
echo $render_options;


sigo sin entender que hace esto <strong>AaAa</strong> dentro de un select no deben haber ese tipo de etiquetas. Link si deseas agregar un texto al select, debes usar un label y usar CSS para posicionarlo.

